# I want to add values while a recursive loop unfolds

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, avl-tree

This is a bottom up approach to check if the tree is an AVL tree or not. So how this code works is:

Suppose this is a tree :

```
        8
    3      10
  2
1
```

The leaf node is checked that it is a leaf node(here 1). It then unfolds one recursion when the node with data 2 is the current value. The value of cl = 1, while it compares the right tree. The right branch of 2 is empty i.e does not have any children so the avl_compare will have (1, 0) which is allowed.

After this i want to add one value to cl so that when the node with data 3 is the current value, the value of cl = 2. avl_check is an assignment question. I have done this on my own but i need some help here to play with recursive functions.

```
def avl_check(self):

    cl = cr = 0
    if(self.left):
        self.left.avl_check()
        cl+=1

    if(self.right):
        self.right.avl_check()
        cr += 1

    if(not self.avl_compare(cl,cr)):
            print("here")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
Specifically, provide code needed to reproduce the problem, and your tracing output so far.

Comment: "I need some help here" is not a problem statement.  What *does* your code do?  You've described what you expect at each stage, but simple testing demonstrates that your code doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you don't seem to understand local and global variables.  **cl** and **cr** are local variables; with the given control flow, the only values they can ever have are 0 and 1.  Remember that each instance of the routine gets a new set of local variables: you set them to 0, perhaps increment to 1, and then you return.  This does *not* affect the values of the variables in other instances of the function.

A deeper problem is that you haven't thought this through for larger trees.  Assume that you *do* learn to use global variables and correct these increments.  Take your current tree, insert nodes 4, 9, 10, and 11 (nicely balanced).  Walk through your algorithm, tracing the values of **cl** and **cr**.  By the time you get to node 10, **cl** is disturbingly more than the tree depth -- I think this is a fatal error in your logic.

---

Think through this again: a recursive routine should not have global variables, except perhaps for the data store of a dynamic programming implementation (which does not apply here).  The function should check for the base case and return something trivial (such as 0 or 1).  Otherwise, the function should reduce the problem *one simple step* and recur; when the recursion returns, the function does something simple with the result and returns the new result to its parent.

Your task is relatively simple:

```
Find the depths of the two subtrees.
If their difference > 1, return False
else return True
```

You should already know how to check the depth of a tree.  Implement this first.  After that, make your implementation more intelligent: checking the depth of a subtree should *also* check its balance at each step.  That will be your final solution.